# Get Predecessors of a Task along with its Start - Id and End - Id using a single request

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, project-server, project-online

My requirement is to fetch all the task links of a Project with Start - Id and End - Id of every task link.

Currently I am only able to fetch `LinkId`, `ProjUid`, Lag and Dependency type using REST API:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('ProjectGUID')/TaskLinks
```

Then to Get **Start - Id** and **End - Id**, I have to again send two additional API requests and it takes a lot of time when I have to fetch a total of **8000+ Task Links** in a project with **8500 tasks**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get Predecessors for all tasks in a single request, you can only get predecessor for a specific task

```
/Tasks('<TaskGUID>')/Predecessors
```

Additionally, you can also use **`ProjectData`** to get all tasks with specific fields

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'{project guid}')/Tasks()?$Select=TaskName,TaskId
```

Comment: Although, it is possible to fetch all the TaskLinks that are there in the project using the endpoint in the question.

Even if I use "/Tasks('<TaskGUID>')/Predecessors", to get the predecessor Id, I have to send another request "/Tasks('<TaskGUID>')/Predecessors('<TaskLinkId>')/Start". This is what I'm trying to avoid as I have to fetch predecessors for 8000+ tasks with 8000+ links.

Comment: I defined a enterprise custom object for the Project Web App and fetched it using ProjectData. That solved my problem.